# How can VLC be made to stretch a video such that it fills a display?

Tags: vlc

I have a video of dimensions 960 x 720 (aspect ratio 4:3) and I have a display of 1920 x 1080 (aspect ratio 16:9). I want the video stretched -- with no respect given to its original aspect ratio -- such that it fills the entire display. Note that I do *not* mean to crop the video.

How could this be done from the command line for individual videos (i.e. not as a general setting for all videos played)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## VLC Aspect Ratio

By selecting the correct **aspect ratio**, a video that would normally have black bars either at the sides or top&bottom may appear to be a video that can fit your screen.

Most modern **wide screen** *laptop* computers have a **16:9** aspect ratio, this might not be the case for you.

### Original Aspect Ratio

[image: Video on Original Aspect Ratio]

### Instructions

1. **Open** Video
2. **Pause** Video
3. **Double Click** video to go into full screen
4. **Righ Click** video to open menu
   [image: VLC MENU]
5. Go into **Video** -> **Aspect Ratio**
6. **Select** your aspect ratio. 16:9 for me.
7. **Play** and *enjoy* :
   [image]

Remember your aspect ratio may be different from mine. If your computer screen is not 16:9 try some other values until you get the right one.

**Un-stretch Video**

To watch videos on their original aspect ratio (without stretching) but covering the entire screen follow the steps above but select the correct aspect ratio under **Video** -> **Crop**.

Default must be kept under **Aspect Ratio** for this to work or nothing will need to be cropped.

### Return to defaults

Return all values you changed to **default**.

## Command Line VLC

Use command `vlc --aspect-ratio 16:9 -L -f /directory/to/file/filename`.
Change the aspect ratio value to your screen's aspect ratio and it should play full screen without borders. See [VLC command line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) for more options.

Comment: and now from the command line? ;)

Comment: Good answer +1, you should leave @incBrain a comment using the @ to get there attention and tell them you add the request, it will likely get you a +1.

Comment: @incBrain Added the command line alternative. Thanx for the recommendation markkirby

Comment: @Torrien thank you for the nice answer dude. +1

Comment: @incBrain Remember to select it as the right answer. Check Mark bellow the up or down vote options.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help and for your clear, detailed solution!

Comment: if I change the aspect ratio, it has no effect on my Ubuntu 2021.10

Answer (score 8):

## Shortcuts

You can cycle through the different **a**spect ratios with <kbd>A</kbd>.

While you didn't want to **c**rop the video this can be done with <kbd>C</kbd>, cycling through audio tracks is <kbd>B</kbd> and subtitles is… <kbd>V</kbd>.

You can find the complete list of shortcuts in the VLC settings menu.

Comment: Super, thanks for that helpful extra information.